# access jquery json data after load?

Tags: json

How do I access my data from outside the getJSON command?

```
//LOAD JSON
$.getJSON("users.js", function(data) {
   numberOfPieces = data.users.length;
   alert("Loaded "+numberOfPieces); //   <------WORKS
});

//Select a piece
var pieceSelected = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberOfPieces));
alert("pieceSelected: "+data.users[pieceSelected].Name); //   <------RETURNS "data is not defined"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that function parameters are scoped to that function and inaccessible outside of the function. By using a variable outside of the scope, things should work as expected.

```
var piecesData;

//LOAD JSON
$.getJSON("users.js", function(data) {
   piecesData = data;
   numberOfPieces = data.users.length;
   alert("Loaded "+numberOfPieces); //   <------WORKS
});

//Select a piece
var pieceSelected = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberOfPieces));
alert("pieceSelected: "+ piecesData.users[pieceSelected].Name);
```